# background services stop when the app is closed via the BACK button

Tags: android, eclipse, background-service

A background service in Android stops running when the user exits the app using the BACK button. The same service works fine if the app is in foreground or in background (clicking the HOME button).

there are 3 cases:

1. Keep the app running: every 15 seconds a notification is shown (OK).
2. Put the app in background by clicking the HOME button: notifications keep showing (OK)
3. Click the BACK button (this closes the app): the background service is stopped and no more notifications are shown (BUG)

Expected behavior

Also in case #3, the notifications should keep running every 15 seconds.

my entire source is below

**MainActivity.java**

```
    package com.example.service_demo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private TextView timerValue;
    private Button startTimer;
    private Button cancleTimer;
    Intent i;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mapview();

    }

    private void mapview() {

        timerValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timertext);
        startTimer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.starttimer);
        cancleTimer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancletimer);
        startTimer.setOnClickListener(this);
        cancleTimer.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        i = new Intent(this, SimpleService.class);
        if (isMyServiceRunning()) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Service is running,",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                    SimpleService.BROADCAST_ACTION));
            startTimer.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "There is no service running",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == startTimer) {
            startTimer.setEnabled(false);
            i = new Intent(this, SimpleService.class);
            startService(i);
            registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                    SimpleService.BROADCAST_ACTION));
        } else if (v == cancleTimer) {
            i = new Intent(this, SimpleService.class);
            stopService(i);
            timerValue.setText("00:00:00");
            startTimer.setEnabled(true);

        }
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            updateUI(intent);
        }

    };

    private void updateUI(Intent intent) {
        String str = intent.getStringExtra("textval");
        timerValue.setText(str);

    }

    private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager
                .getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (SimpleService.class.getName().equals(
                    service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
        i = new Intent(this, SimpleService.class);
        startService(i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
        System.exit(0); // system.exit(0) is mendatory for my app so it can't be
                        // removed
    }

}
```

**SimpleService**

```
    package com.example.service_demo;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SimpleService extends Service {

    private NotificationManager mNM;
    private long startTime = 0L;
    long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
    long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
    long updatedTime = 0L;
    long basestart = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    long timeswap = 0L;
    int secs = 0;
    int mins = 0;
    int hour = 0;
    Intent intent;
    String s;
    public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.example.service_demo.MainActivity";
    private int NOTIFICATION = 1;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mNM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", 2000).show();

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), 0, 1000);
            }
        });
        t.start();

        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        mNM.cancel(NOTIFICATION);

        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
            timer.purge();
            timer = null;
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stoped", 2000).show();
    }

    class RemindTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            timeInMilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis() - basestart;
            timeSwapBuff = timeswap;
            updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

            secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
            mins = secs / 60;
            hour = mins / 60;

            secs = secs % 60;
            mins = mins % 60;

            s = "" + String.format("%02d", hour) + ":" + ""
                    + String.format("%02d", mins) + ":"
                    + String.format("%02d", secs);
            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("00:00:15")) {
                showNotification();
            }
            intent.putExtra("textval", s);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }

    private void showNotification() {
        // In this sample, we'll use the same text for the ticker and the
        // expanded notification
        CharSequence text = s;

        // Set the icon, scrolling text and timestamp
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                text, System.currentTimeMillis());

        // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this
        // notification
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

        // Set the info for the views that show in the notification panel.
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Notification Label", text,
                contentIntent);

        // Send the notification.
        mNM.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey Why are you using System.exit(0); you can remove and then try.

Comment: Instead of showing a Toast, can you try print a Log and see whether it works even after the app is quitted.

Answer (score 1):

In the method `onStartCommand()` of the service, return `START_STICKY`.
The service will continue to run until you explicitly call `stopSelf()` in the service or call `stopService()` from your activity.

Comment: In the method onStartCommand() of the service if i use START_STICKY then if i press back button and launch the application again than it will start timer from 00:00:00.
But i want my timer to be run continuesly until i press Stop timer button

Comment: `START_STICKY` creates a new timer from "00:00:00" every time i relaunch my application instead of continuous timer

Comment: Sounds like your application launcher activity's onCreate() method is starting your service again every time, you can have a boolean in the service to indicate whether it's running or net .. if it running don;t start your counter

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing foreground service. [foreground service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground)

Foreground service displays notification and is never stopped.

Implement this code snippet in your service's onCreate().

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, getText(R.string.ticker_text),
        System.currentTimeMillis());
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.notification_title),
        getText(R.string.notification_message), pendingIntent);
startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Comment: i can put notification task in a foreground but what i want is that my timer should keep running until i press stop timer button. i mean to say that i must get notification when my timer string is 00:00:15 and my timer should keep running whenever i relaunch my application which was killed by pressing back button

Comment: you can run your timer in Service class so that it doesn't get stop when you go back. And when button is clicked stop your Service.

Comment: My timer runs in Service class itself. just check the code again

Comment: I mean, If you show some simple notification in onCreate() of service then using code snippet above then your service will not get killed.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
notifyIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
notifyIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
```